# Topological Sort Algorithm and Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, topological-sort

I'm working on an algorithm to the following problem:

We have a set amount of courses and for each course, we are given it's prerequisites. Find the longest sequence of courses such that every course in the sequence, the previous course is it's prereq.

I know this is clearly a problem where topological sorting will come in handy, but I am having some difficulty with the algorithm and implementation. For the algorithm, my first thought is we should be able to run a standard topological sort algorithm and just keep a counter that counts if a course is a pre-req or not when we "see" it.

I've decided that it would be best to represent the graph as an adjacency list. Here's kind of a rough idea of where I'm at with the implementation thus far,

```
 public Vertex{
     private String courseName;
     private Vertex[] edges; //Represents all of this courses pre-reqs.

     public addEdge(Vertex v); //Add's a pre-req
     public getEdges();        //Returns array of edges
     public getEdge(int index);//Return edge at specific index
 }
```

And then in the main program, the "graph" will simply be an array of Vertexes:

```
 Vertex graph[] = new Vertex[num];
```

If anyone has any thoughts, links, hints, etc. on either the algorithm, or implementation please feel free to share. I am aiming for O(n + m) time where n is the number of courses and m is the number of pre-reqs.

Comment: So are you asking us to explain Topological Sort to you? Look for tutorials then. Can't understand something specific, come to us. :)

Comment: I know I'm mostly wired towards graphs, so: Every course sis a node, every prerequisite is a directed edge between the nodes (decide on the direction - not really important which way you do it, as long as it is consistent). Then find the longest path in the graph. Then it's just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: @therainmaker I feel comfortable with Topological Sort, but I am looking for help in applying it to this problem.

Comment: @shapiroyaacov : The graph formulation you've explained is correct. However, the last line about making it finding the longest path in the graph is incorrect in this case. That problem is NP-hard, and not required here. Talen : You can apply topological sort to the graph formulation explained above. Any doubts remaining?

Comment: @therainmaker, we obviously should assume the graph to be acyclic, and then the problem is by no means NP-hard, and shapiro yaacov's link gives you all the details. Namely, this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths

Comment: @Petr : Thanks for your point. I blindly went on the NP route by looking at the problem. Should've spared more thought. Even then, topological sort for course pre-requisites isn't the same as longest path.

Comment: @therainmaker, I agree that the topological sort is not the longest path, but OP seems to ask exactly for how to apply the topsort to their problem. This is a valid question (though might be offtopic for SO), and the link above answers this question.